# php html to print 1/3 of an A4 page w/Dot Matrix Epson LX 300+ printer

Tags: php, html, printing

I have drawn a form which fits on each ticket(1/3 of A4 form page) quite well. However, I cannot figure out how to make the printer feed ONLY 1/3 OF THE PAGE after each spool. What ends up happening is a whole page is fed in, and two tickets are wasted each print. Of course, I could just tell the guy to feed the paper back out after every ticket, but then he would have to worry about lining it up correctly every time.

I tried my CSS like this, but there is not solve my problem

```
@media print { html, body { width: 210mm; height: 94mm; }   }
@page { size: 210mm 94mm; margin-left: 20mm; margin-top: 20mm; }
.print:last-child {
 page-break-after: auto;
}
```

Any ideas, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a page break after each `<ticket_element>`

```
@media print {
    ticket_element {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

This code will always break page after each ticket;

If you want an X amount of ticket you could create a invisible element after X number of ticket and bind page break after this separator element.